# Use "so as not to"?

Tags: grammar

This is a quote from Doctor Who series, when two teachers are talking about a smart girl:

"She lets her knowledge out a bit at a time
so as not to embarrass me."

This means that she shows her knowledge just a bit for not embarrassing him or
the action of she shows her smartness just a few times don't embarrass him?

What could replace "so as not to" in this sentence?

Comment: She only displays her knowledge in small pieces **so that she will not embarrass him**  by making it obvious how much more she knows than he does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question

> What could replace "so as not to" in this sentence

The answer is **in order not to**:

"She lets her knowledge out a bit at a time *in order not to* embarrass me."

The following is something free I'll throw in:

The word **[lest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lest)** is a common but "formal"  conjunction that means

*so as not to* or *in order that one should not*, but it uses the subject of the sentence:

She lets her knowledge out a bit at a time, lest she embarrass me.

Answer (score 3):

"She lets her knowledge out a bit at a time **to avoid** embarrass**ing** me."

She does not show off her intelligence because she does not want to show how much smarter she is than the speaker. The speaker would be embarrassed if she displayed her intelligence more often.